# Diversi modi di tradurre "in such a way that" in italiano

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Penso che l'espressione inglese "in such a way that" si possa tradurre come "in modo che". Ad esempio,

> Dovresti tradurre il tuo post in inglese *in modo che* tutti gli utenti lo possano capire.

Mi chiedo però se esistano altri modi di tradurre questa espressione in italiano, più adatti magari ad altri contesti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nel tuo caso, "in such a way that" potrebbe essere sostituito con "so that" a dare un fine, quindi *perché*, *cosicché*, *dimodoché*, *di modo che* + congiuntivo sono tutti appropriati.

La traduzione letterale di "in such a way that" è però "in modo tale che", che ha più una sfumatura... "modale". Se lo uso voglio porre l'accento sulla maniera in cui faccio qualcosa, al fine di raggiungere il mio obiettivo. Come userei "in such a
 way" invece di "so" in inglese.

[Esempio (al contrario)](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2510946):

> La lista degli account deve essere ordinata in modo tale che gli account di tipo feedback vengano elaborati prima degli altri.

Answer (score 1):

Usa 'affinché', 'acché', 'di talché'—e anche, magari, 'perché'—che sono parole molto più eleganti di 'in modo che'.

E, in ultimo, non dimenticare 'dimodoché', che è una parola molto interessante.

Comment: Pur non avendo niente contro “in modo che”, sono d'accordo con le alternative proposte da Elberich, stando attenti al fatto che alcune sono un po' ricercate (e “di talché” è usato quasi solo nel linguaggio giuridico (in particolare nelle sentenze) e “appartiene al genere di quei vocaboli che talvolta i giuristi adoprano per conferire alla loro lingua sembianze auliche e paludate”, [dice uno studioso della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/talch)).

Comment: Anche *cosicché* (o, staccato, *così che*).