# Differenze di uso tra "forse" e "magari"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Non riesco a capire quali siano le differenze di uso tra "forse" e "magari". Per esempio, in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5384/diversi-modi-di-tradurre-in-such-a-way-that-in-italiano), io avevo scritto la frase

> Mi chiedo però se esistano altri modi di tradurre questa espressione in italiano, più adatti *forse* ad altri contesti

che poi è stata corretta in questo modo:

> Mi chiedo però se esistano altri modi di tradurre questa espressione in italiano, più adatti *magari* ad altri contesti.

Perché è meglio usare "magari" in questa frase?

Comment: "[Magari](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/magari/)" viene dal greco "felice" ed esprime un forte desiderio. "[Forse](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forse/) indica un dubbio. Ma non saprei dirti, da dilettante quale sono, perché nella tua frase suoni meglio "magari" di "forse".

Comment: Mi associo al commento di @writingthesis, "magari" è utilizzato come un'espressione di desiderio o ironica, "forse" esprime sempre un dubbio.
In questo caso è come se nella prima frase fosse espresso il _dubbio che_ altri modi di traduzione _non siano adatti se non ad altri contesti_; nella seconda frase invece è come se si esprimesse il _desiderio che siano adatti_ ad altri contesti.

Comment: I due sensi di “magari” come quasi sinonimo di “forse” (“magari domani piove”) e come premessa a un desiderio (“magari Gigi fosse qui!”) sono ben diversi. Nel caso in esame, io non avrei corretto la frase originaria, ma anche la seconda versione non ne cambia il senso e dà solo un tono più colloquiale e vagamente più ipotetico.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Magari*, nel linguaggio colloquiale, assume una serie di significati piú o meno affini:

> 3. cong., fam., con valore concessivo, seguito da congiuntivo, anche se, quandanche: *andrò, magari fosse l’ultima cosa che faccio*
> 4. avv., probabilmente, forse: *magari verrà domani*, *magari si è offeso* | eventualmente, semmai: *magari chiamami prima di venire*
> 5. avv., addirittura, persino: *sarebbe disposto magari a rimetterci*
> 6. avv., fam., piuttosto: *magari aspetto un’ora, ma devo assolutamente parlargli*
>
> De Mauro, «[Magari](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/magari)»

Le frasi da Lei portate ad esempio hanno il medesimo significato; non vi sono nemmeno differenze distributive tra *magari* e *forse*. L’unica differenza è, per l’appunto, di registro: *magari* è piú informale di *forse*.

Comment: Posso capire una preferenza per il *lei* anche se non lo userei. Ma, sinceramente, *Lei* con la maiuscola mi pare un po' eccessivo. Vedi http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9/ci-diamo-del-tu

Comment: Il «tu» vorrei riservarlo alle persone con le quali ho un minimo di confidenza. La maiuscola è dovuta al desiderio — un po’ pedante, lo riconosco — di distinguere il pronome di cortesia dal pronome personale femminile di terza persona. Ma non è necessario farlo, ché il contesto basta e avanza a disambiguare, perciò accetto volentieri l’appunto.

Comment: Comunque benvenuto! E spero che non ti secchi se usiamo il tu anche con te. `:-)`

Comment: La ringrazio. No, non mi secca affatto, non si preoccupi. Sono un ospite, e in quanto tale mi adeguo volentieri alle vostre regole. Dopotutto si tratta di minuzie. :-)

Comment: un ospite? di chi? non degli altri partecipanti, o no?